# Transform a summation of infinity independent events into the integral of these events.

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega$ be the universe set and $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ be a partition of $\Omega$ (i.e, they are pairwise disjoint and their union is $\Omega$). If these conditions a set $A$ can be written as
$$
A = A\cap x_1\cup A\cap x_2 \cup ... \cup A\cap x_n.
$$
and the probability of $A$ can be written as (Total Probability Theorem)
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A) &= P(A\cap x_1\cup A\cap x_2 \cup ... \cup A\cap x_n), \\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A\cap x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X=x_i)P(A|X=x_i).
\end{aligned}
$$

I would like to do the same for the casa where x is a continuous variable, but I do not know how. Any suggestion?

The point of this is that I want to reach the following conditional equation
$$
P(A) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(A|X=x)f_X(x)dx.
$$

Edited:

To be more specific, I what to reach this
$$
P(X \leq x, X+Y \leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X \leq x, X+Y \leq t | X=u)f_x(u)du.
$$

Answer (score 1):

That's fine.

Note that you have: $\displaystyle\mathsf P(X\leq x, X+Y\leq t) ~=~\int_{-\infty}^x \mathsf P(Y=t-u\mid X=u)~f_X(u)\operatorname d u$

And if both $X,Y$ are continuous, that $\displaystyle ~=~ \int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^{t-u} f_{Y\mid X=u}(v)~f_X(u)\operatorname d v\operatorname d u$